# Why did this spoiler syntax not work

Tags: support, spoilers

I wanted to write the following as a spoiler, in an answer, but the syntax >! did not work.

> ! Essentially, 
> $\log_5(6/5) = \log_5(6) - \log_5(5) = a/b -1$ 
> since $\log_56=\dfrac{\log_4 6}{\log_4 5} = \dfrac{a}{b} $

Can somebody point out what went wrong?

Comment: FYI, see the network Meta post [What's the exact syntax for spoiler markup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/72877). Although it's almost $12$ years old, I believe not much has changed as far as that syntax goes. However, regarding initial spaces before the '>!', my testing shows this only always works properly if there are $3$ or fewer initial spaces. Also, note that instead of a '\' at the end of each line, you could also use '<br>' instead, as well as just putting all of your text into $1$ line, with the '<br>' causing each part to appear on a separate line.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The line breaks are the issue. If you remove the linebreaks or start each line with `>!`, you can get the desired result, as I show below:

> Essentially, 
>  $\log_5(6/5) = \log_5(6) - \log_5(5) = a/b -1$ 
>  since $\log_56=\dfrac{\log_4 6}{\log_4 5} = \dfrac{a}{b} $

You ought to be able to click edit to see what's going on there, but just in case,

```
>! Essentially, \
>! $\log_5(6/5) = \log_5(6) - \log_5(5) = a/b -1$ \
>! since $\log_56=\dfrac{\log_4 6}{\log_4 5} = \dfrac{a}{b} $
```

is the text I've inputted.

Comment: Thanks for the text in code mode, because it says 
"Suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites."